# SSIS Balanced Data Distributor - Increase number of operations?

Tags: ssis, balanced-data-distributor

As per the attached, we have a Balanced Data Distributor set up in a data transformation covering about 2 million rows.  The script tasks are identical - each one opens a connection to oracle and executes first a delete and then an insert.  (This isn't relevant but it's done that way due to parameter issues with the Ole DB command and the Microsoft Ole DB provider for Oracle...)

[image]

The issue I'm running into is no matter how large I make my buffers or how many concurrent executions I configure, the BDD will not execute more than five concurrent processes at a time.

I've pulled back hundreds of thousands of rows in a larger buffer, and it just gets divided 5 ways.  I've tried this on multiple machines - the current shot is from a 16 core server with -1 concurrent executions configured on the package - and no matter what, it's always 5 parallel jobs.

5 is better than 1, but with 2.5 million rows to insert/update, 15 rows per second at 5 concurrent executions isn't much better than 2-3 rows per second with 1 concurrent execution.

Can I force the BDD to use more paths, and if so how?

Comment: Haven't had a valid BDD use case yet, but would you be able to change your pattern to be a straight inert into a staging table on Oracle and then you perform your delete and inserts after the dataflow completes via an Execute SQL Task?

Comment: It's off point of the question, but the original pattern was a full delete and repopulate.  The insert portion (without deletes) took 4 days when running single threaded.  The Oracle connection usage in SSIS is notoriously slow.  FYI this particular process is now much more intelligent and most of the time the updates will only be a few hundred rows.  The question focuses on BDD because we'll be making more of these types of processes in future and we need better performance tuning.

Comment: This looked like an interesting component I didn't know about, so I just watched an intro video by Debarchan Sarkar. He mentioned that "it works best with up to 5 flows" but didn't say anything about it being a limit. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/hh369962.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer:

Yes BDD can make use of more than five paths. You shouldn't be doing anything special to force it, by definition it should automatically do it for you. Then why isn't it using more than 5 paths? Because your source is producing data faster than your destination can consume causing backpressure. To resolve it, you've to tune your destination components.

Long answer:

In theory, "the BDD takes input data and routes it in equal proportions to it's outputs, however many there are." In your set up, there are 10 outputs. So input data should be equally distributed to all the 10 outputs at the same time and you should see 10 paths executing at the same time - again in theory.

But another concept of BDD is "instead of routing individual rows, the BDD operates on buffers on data." Which means data flow engine initiates a buffer, fills it with as many rows as possible, and moves that buffer to the next component (script destination in your case). As you can see 5 buffers are used each with the same number of rows. If additional buffers were started, you'd have seen more paths being used. SSIS couldn't use additional buffers and ultimately additional paths because of a mechanism called backpressure; it happens when the source produces data faster than the destination can consume it. If it happens all memory would be used up by the source data and SSIS will not have any memory to use for the transformation and destination components. So to avoid it, SSIS limits the number of active buffers. It is set to 5 (can't be changed) which is exactly the number of threads you're seeing.

PS: The text within quotes is from [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlperf/archive/2011/05/25/the-balanced-data-distributor-for-ssis.aspx)

Comment: I'll have to digest this a bit, but I think you've hit it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a property in SSIS data flow tasks called EngineThreads which determines how many flows can be run concurrently, and its default value is 5 (in SSIS 2012 its default value is 10, so I'm assuming you're using SSIS 2008 or earlier.) The optimal value is dependent on your environment, so some testing will probably be required to figure out what to put there.

Here's a [Jamie Thomson article](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2005/10/02/SSIS-Nugget_3A00_-Engine-Threads.aspx) with a bit more detail.

Comment: It's a good idea.  Sadly, EngineThreads on my data flow tasks defaulted to 10 as well.  But I'll play with it and see if it makes a difference anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Another interesting thing I've discovered via [this article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/247883/An-Introduction-to-SSIS-Balanced-Data-Distributor).

> [T]his component uses an internal buffer of 9,947 rows (as per the
>   experiment, I found so) and it is pre-set. There is no way to override
>   this. As a proof, instead of 10 lac rows, we will use only 9,947 (Nine
>   thousand nine forty seven ) rows in our input file and will observe
>   the behavior. After running the package, we will find that all the
>   rows are being transferred to the first output component and the other
>   components received nothing.
>
> Now let us increase the number of rows in our input file from 9,947 to
>   9,948 (Nine thousand nine forty eight). After running the package, we
>   find that the first output component received 9,947 rows while the
>   second output component received 1 row.

So I notice in your first buffer run that you pulled 50,000 records. Those got divided into 9,984 record buckets and passed to each output. So essentially the BDD takes the records it gets from the buffer and passes them out in ~10,000 record increments to each output. So in this case perhaps your source is the bottleneck.

Perhaps you'll need to split your original Source query in half and create two BDD-driven data flows to in essence double your parallel throughput.

Comment: I've played with buffers.  Actually that article is wrong - you can override it.  The number of rows is determined by taking the data flow tasks DefaultBufferSize and dividing by rowsize.  The resulting set is then divided by 5.  If I increase the buffer size, the rowset size increases and so does the divide by five limit, so if I double the buffer, it pulls about 100k rows, and then each path gets 20k rows.